# Set Process ID of apk

Tags: android

I have a req. like I have Application A created by me and APK of Application B.
Is it possible for me to set the process id and user id both same for the apk as well as application A. I don't have manifest of application B since its an apk. Is it possible for me to run the apk and an application of my own in the same process? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `sharedUserId` in both `manifest.xml` files.
The process id (normal install) must not be the same on each device. You get the id from the device.

Comment: Hi Bob, Thanks. But, I will have the apk alone. I am new to android. I think apk doesn't have manifest in it right? If that is the case how can I do it? Please suggest.

Comment: You need the Manifast.xml is you apk maybe open Source?

Comment: Sorry bob. I am not able to understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the manifest.xml of the apk, you can set the [sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sharedUserId).

EDIT:

If you Have only the apk file. You can use the [android-apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/), this tool allows you to "decode resources to nearly original form and rebuild them after making some modifications". So you can have access to the AndroidManifest.xml and there change the [sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sharedUserId).

Comment: THanks Uriel. But, what I have is only apk and no manifest file. Is there any way without going to manifest and doing this? Please help anyone.

Comment: Maybe you can change the suffix of the file from apk to zip and open it. Than you can look inside the AndroidManifest.xml file, and see if it has sharedUserId.

Comment: No, Uriel. I am not able to open the manifest file using eclipse or edit it. Its in unicode. My question is will we be able to update the manifest file from APK and if its possible how? Will the new changes be reflected after changing?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know. Try and tell us what happen.

Comment: There is a tool called apktool using which we can open the manifest file and update it back to apk again with our desired changes.   Link : http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/

Comment: Reverse engineering. I like it :)